# How to prove that $f(x,y) = \frac{2x^3+3y^2}{x^2y+xy^2}$ is not homogeneous?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

How to prove that the following function is not homogeneous?

> $f(x,y) = \frac{2x^3+3y^2}{x^2y+xy^2}$

**Definition:**

> A function $F(x,y)$ of the variables $x$ and $y$ is called *homogeneous* of degree $n$ if for any parameter $t$
>
> $F(tx, ty) = t^n F(x,y)$.

So in this function, it is not possible to write the expression in the form $t^n F(x,y)$. How do I prove that this function is not homogeneous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute $f(tx,ty)$:

$$f(tx,ty) = \frac{2(tx)^3 + 3(ty)^2}{(tx)^2 (ty) + (tx)(ty)^2}.$$

Now, can you factor out $t$ to get $f(tx,ty) = t^n f(x,y)$? If not, then your function is not homogenous. (I have left you a little bit of work to do.)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y) = \frac{2x^3+3y^2}{x^2y+xy^2}$$
Let's fix a $t \ne 0$
$$f(tx,ty) = \frac{2x^3+3t^{-1}y^2}{x^2y+xy^2}$$

$$t^n f(x,y) = t^n\frac{2x^3+3y^2}{x^2y+xy^2}$$

So we could not find any $n$ to make $f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y)$ for all $x,y$